# Select inputs are duplicated when using fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am loading a content using fancybox like this

```
$.fancybox($('#myDiv').html());

<div id="myDiv" style="display: none;">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option>Abc</option>
        <option>Cde</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

in js when fancybox is showing the content I am getting 4 options, why?

```
$('#mySelect option').size() => 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$('#myDiv').html()` is cloning the `select` elements from `#myDiv` so you have two hidden `select` elements and two inside the fancybox.

Instead of this :

```
$.fancybox($('#myDiv').html());
```

... I would rather do :

```
$.fancybox('#myDiv');
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aT7Ee/)**

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem like this question and I would like to know n your sample how to set the different properties like modal, showCloseButton, ... Can you help please?

Comment: @David : just add the proper options like this http://jsfiddle.net/vrjkujm5/ make sure you use the right options according to the version you are using.

Comment: You just made my day. Thanks!